# disable click event on first column

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me how to disable the click event on first column and the other columns should be clickable. I have tried several different ways like slice

> td.slice() after tr element and also td:gt(0)

etc and was unsuccessful. I had been banging my head since 2 days and I didn't find any relevant solutions out on google.

```
$('#Table tbody tr').on("click",function(){
                    var aPos Table.fnGetPosition(this);
                    var aData = Table.fnGetData( aPos[6] );
                    //aData = $(this).parent().parent().html();
                    xyz = $(this).parent().parent().find("td").eq(1).html();                    
                    yzx= $(this).parent().parent().find("td").eq(7).html();
                    zxy= $(this).parent().parent().find("td").eq(2).html();
                    alert(aPos);

            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `stopPropogation` on first column click [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/aQEY9/)

**Edit:** Added demo and fixed `.find('td:first')`

```
$('#Table tr').find('td:first').on('click', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: That's going to say everything but the first table row; not the column.

Comment: @Tejs yea, i messed up.. updating the post

Comment: Its is not good either, it would only disable the first row and first column click but would not disable the second row first column click

Comment: @user525146 Check the update.. yea i messed up column with row

Comment: @Vega I changed it to .find('td:gt(0)') which had disabled the click on the first column and enable click on the other columns. Not sure if something is wrong in my table which is opposite of expected

Comment: @user525146 I am more inclined on the above posted which bind the handler to the tr and not td(as in your post). `$('#Table tbody tr').find('td:gt(0)')` -> will bind the handler to `td's`. Did I confuse you? Let me know and I can give you an example. >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/aQEY9/1/ <<

Comment: @Vega Yes, I am little confused but when I had .find(td:first) would disable the click on the first row but when I click on the second row first column checkbox would trigger the alert I had placed to check

Comment: @user525146 Do you mean that you have a checkbox which has a click handler? `$('tr').find(td:first)` -> finds all first col in all row, not just first row. Can you check the demo or update the demo as your requirement and let me know. http://jsfiddle.net/skram/aQEY9/1/

Answer (score 0):

add some kind of unique identifier on the first column and

```
$('identifier').click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

I think you can also target first column with the n-th child thing but I am not sure of the exact syntax. Maybe something like

```
$('table tr td:(nth-child(1)').on('click', function(){
    return false;
});
```

or something like the above, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some kind of identifier to the columns you want to use:

```
<tr>
    <td class="dontClickMe"></td>
    <td class="clickMe"></td>
</tr>
```

Then it's as simple as:

```
$('.clickMe').on('click', function() { ... });
```